# "'HTMLDocument' is undefined" in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've been looking around, and everywhere it is said that IE8 do have HTMLDocument and Element classes. Unfortunately when I'm trying to access it, all I get is:

```
"'HTMLDocument' is undefined"
"'HTMLElement' is undefined"
"'Element' is undefined"
"'Document' is undefined"
```

I've been suspecting that it's consoles fault, but same thing happens when I load it from the script and prototype for i.e. Array does exist normally.

Could it be that I'm trying access it in the wrong way? I'm using:

```
typeof HTMLDocument.prototype.getElementsByClassName != 'function'
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason, why don't you do simply: `(typeof document.getElementsByClassName !== 'function')`?

Comment: Did you already check if ie 8 is in compat mode?

Comment: Unfortunately ie8 is in quirks mode by default, and my script has to work on "default ie8 user" machine, so changing anything in browser is out of questron.

Comment: @Teemu: I want to add my own version of getElementsByClassName if there's no in the browser. I need to add it to document as well as to element prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it. IE sets itself to Quirks mode for the page I've been testing it on. Unfortunately I can't set document mode in this case, so adding my own getElementsByClassName is a lost cause...

For those that can edit html document they are working on, add this meta tag to assure IE8 will act as IE8:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but may be, that's because you're in compatibility mode.

You can make something like:

```js
var elementPrototype = typeof HTMLElement !== "undefined" 
        ? HTMLElement.prototype : Element.prototype;
```

**But this will work for IE7+**.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasClass = function (el, searchClass) {
    return el.className.test(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + searchClass + '(\\s|$)'));
};
```

You can't add methods to `HTMLElement.prototype` in older versions of IE.

You can always add this to the `Object.prototype` object but it's frowned on

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Prateek19/3WfAc/1/)